# open PDF in new tab C#

Tags: c#, jquery, pdf, itext

i want to open the PDF file in new tab when i display it on the web.
but without clicking just a function that open the file in a new tab.
this is my display function:

```
private void DisplayPage()
    {        
        string path = CanvasWritingStepImages._pdfName;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);

        if (buffer != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Formulike.pdf");
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Error("Buffer was Null!");
            throw new Exception("PDF ERROR");
        }
    }
```

i'm using "iTextSharp" to work with the PDF file.
it's important that the PDF file will be open on a new tab without any clicking just by the function. 
i just found with button click that open a new tab.

i tried this:
[How to open PDF file in a new tab or window instead of downloading it (using asp.net)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294057/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-a-new-tab-or-window-instead-of-downloading-it-using-asp)

Comment: Fighting with popup blockers (which is what is your question is about - open new window without user action) is very controversial topic. Beware that getting answers that work consistently/will continue working for long time is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue... see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509678/open-byte-array-from-memory-stream-in-new-tab-or-window).

Put your pdf creation code in the `form load` event of a new page.  Then use the code below to open that page in a new tab.

```
string url = "myPDFpage.aspx";
string openWindowScript = string.Format("window.open({0}, '_blank');", url);         
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), openWindowScript, true);
```

If you're not using a `ScriptManager` you can replace the last line with the following:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), openWindowScript, true);
```

If your pdf needs variables to be created, pass them through a query string or store them in a session variable so the new page will have access to them.

**The new tab/window will be blocked unless the user allows popups from your site or has their blocker turned off.**